# Excel: drag row to a new position and automatically insert/remove

Tags: microsoft-excel

I spend a lot of time moving rows around in Excel, both on the Mac and on Windows. I would like to easily drag an excel row into a new position on a spreadsheet and have the spreadsheet insert the row in the new position, not overwrite. Right now I need to first manually create a place for the row to go, then drag it over, then delete the old location. Surely there must be a way to do this in a single operation...?

Comment: select the row, right-click: cut (or CTRL+X), right click the desired location and "paste cut cells"

Comment: @MátéJuhász, could you make that a proper answer so I can accept it? On the Mac it is "insert cut cells"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag and drop rows doesn't work, however you can cut and insert them:

- select the row(s) you want to move (either by clicking on the header, or pressing Shift+Space)
- cut them (right click - Cut or CTRL+X)
- right click destination and select "Insert Cut cells"

*I've access only to Windows version, but should be similar on Mac too*

Answer (score 1):

To move a row, and have it insert somewhere else.

1. Select the row
2. Move your pointer to one of the edges of that row until the cursor changes to the "move" arrow.
3. Hold the shift key
4. click and drag the row, represented as a bar, to the location you want it moved to.
5. Drop.

if you want to copy and drag - same steps, just hold shift & ctrl keys in step 3.

Works on Windows10/Office 365

Answer (score 0):

Mac: Hold down command+shift when you drag.  On my mac, this causes the row/column to automatically reposition down/right instead of overwriting.

Windows: I don't *know* the answer for Windows, but my *guess* is, considering Windows shortcuts are usually the same as Mac, but command becomes ctrl, it's probably ctrl+shift.

Answer (score -1):

To have it happen automatically, I would build a little macro to do what was suggested here. it helps to know the MS shortcut keys such as Ctrl-X to cut.
To do it manually, It sounds like what you want to do is go to the left most column where the row numbers are*. Click the row number to select the whole row, type Ctrl-X to cut it, go to the new location's row number in the left most column**, type Ctrl-V to paste the row there.
If the new row has to be placed in between existing rows, select the row that will be below the new one, right click and select 'Insert'. A new row appears, then Ctrl-V to paste. The old row will still be there but now blank, select it, right-click, 'Delete' (Excel will suggest "shift rows up") click OK.
To the extent that part of what you do is the same every time, build a macro - go to 'View; on the tool bar, then 'Macros' then record a new, name it, assign a shortcut, start recording. When you want to activate it, use the shortcut you created.
*I would create the macro after selecting the row to be moved so it's reusable.
**This will work best if the new row is always in the same place, otherwise two macros are needed.

Comment: Whitespace could be your friend, Tom.